# Could read drectories but not files in android 11 / 12 from react-native

Tags: android, react-native, file, android-11

I am building a simple whatsapp status saver app in react native. as status directory in android 10 or lesser has a diffrent location than android 11 and higher i have checked that with

```
      let StatusDir = null;
      const WhatsAppStatusDir1 = `${RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath}/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses`;
      const WhatsAppStatusDir2 = 
      ${RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath}/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images`;

      const statusDirExists1 = await RNFS.exists(WhatsAppStatusDir1);
      const statusDirExists2 = await RNFS.exists(WhatsAppStatusDir2);
      if (statusDirExists1) {
        StatusDir = WhatsAppStatusDir1;
      } else if (statusDirExists2) {
        StatusDir = WhatsAppStatusDir2;
   }
```

Now i have correct path in my `StatusDir` variable. Then i have written

```
if (StatusDir) {
        const FILES = await RNFS.readDir(StatusDir);
        console.log(FILES);
      } else {
        Alert.alert('WhatsApp status directory does not exist');
      }
```

and i also added the below code in my manifest.xml file

```
<application
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
...
```

now here comes the problem, this code is working extreamly fine in android 9 or 10 but when i try this same code in android 11 or higher empty array s getting printed and i also have seen thatin android 11 or higher i can read directors but not the files inside them. i was serching for solution and fond something like

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I tried that too but problem still persist. I need help.

I want my code to run on android 11 or higher and i want to access whatsapp status files in my app. I have tried everything that i could do but could not find any work around.

Comment: AFAIR `requestLegacyExternalStorage` only works on Android 10 if the device has been upgraded from Android 9.

Comment: ok i will remove it but how to access status files in android 11?

Comment: What is a a status file?

Comment: @Robert, has nothing to do with upgrading. Its just for Android Q/10 devices.

Comment: @blackapps status file means whatsApp status files which are stored in .Statuses folder

Comment: Yes a status file. But what would it be? A txt, pdf, doc or what?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, quite normal for Android 11+ devices.

You can list directories. But only your own files.

The files created by your app.

Has nothing to do with react-native.

Comment: Can you give me any solution how to read files

Comment: Implementing MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE will do.

Comment: As i mentioned I already have used it. It is allowing me to access whatsapp images but whatsapp statuses i can not access

Comment: I wonder how you used it. You did not show.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

i have used it in manifest file

Comment: Yes. That i already saw of course. You do not have to repeat that. But that is not enough. I asked what you did further to use it.